# What it means that + in the c++ process state

Tags: linux, process, ps

I make the `test.cpp` and compile this.

```
int main() {
    while(1);
}
```

`g++ test.cpp`

And `ps -aux | grep a.out`.

The process state a.out is `R+`.

Yes. Of course, the process infinitely runs.

But, I don't understand the `+`

In `ps` manual, `+` is in the foreground process group.

I don't know what it means that `a.out` is in the foreground process group.

```
PROCESS STATE CODES         
       Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output
       specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the
       state of a process:

               D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
               I    Idle kernel thread
               R    running or runnable (on run queue)
               S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to
                    complete)
               T    stopped by job control signal
               t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
               W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
               X    dead (should never be seen)
               Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not
                    reaped by its parent

       For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional
       characters may be displayed:

               <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
               N    low-priority (nice to other users)
               L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and
                    custom IO)
               s    is a session leader
               l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL
                    pthreads do)
               +    is in the foreground process group
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically means that the process executes within a terminal session, occupying it, with a direct user access to it. A background process runs without direct user interactions. Mostly used when you want to continue using the terminal session but also need to run a time demanding computation.

You can change this state of your program by supplying the `&` sign after the launch command:

```
./a.out &
```

And then you can bring your process back by using the `fg` command or by the process id you will get after putting the process in the background.